# Mismatched feature counts in spark data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and I am trying to clean a relatively large dataset. The problem I have is that the feature values seem to be mismatched in the original dataset. It looks something like this for the first line  when I take a summary of the dataset :

```html
|summary   A      B |
---------------------
|count     5     10 |
```

I am trying to find a way to filter based on the row with the lowest count across all features and maintain the ordering.
I would like to have:

```html
|summary   A      B |
---------------------
|count     5     5 |
```

How could I achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches for you to consider:

**Simple approach**

```
# Set up the example df
df = spark.createDataFrame([('count',5,10)],['summary','A','B'])

# +-------+---+---+
# |summary|  A|  B|
# +-------+---+---+
# |  count|  5| 10|
# +-------+---+---+

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

@udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def get_row_min(A,B):
    return min([A,B])

df.withColumn('new_A', get_row_min(col('A'),col('B')))\
  .withColumn('new_B', col('new_A'))\
  .drop('A')\
  .drop('B')\
  .withColumnRenamed('new_A','A')\
  .withColumnRenamed('new_B', 'B')\
  .show()

# +-------+---+---+
# |summary|  A|  B|
# +-------+---+---+
# |  count|  5|  5|
# +-------+---+---+
```

**Generic approach for indirectly specified columns**

```
# Set up df with an extra column (and an extra row to show it works)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('count',5,10,15),
                             ('count',3,2,1)],
                            ['summary','A','B','C'])

# +-------+---+---+---+
# |summary|  A|  B|  C|
# +-------+---+---+---+
# |  count|  5| 10| 15|
# |  count|  3|  2|  1|
# +-------+---+---+---+

@udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def get_row_min_generic(*cols):
    return min(cols)

exclude = ['summary']


df3 = df2.withColumn('min_val', get_row_min_generic(*[col(col_name) for col_name in df2.columns 
                                                      if col_name not in exclude]))

exclude.append('min_val') # this could just be specified in the list 
                          # from the beginning instead of appending

new_cols = [col('min_val').alias(c) for c in df2.columns if c not in exclude]

df_out = df3.select(['summary']+new_cols)
df_out.show()

# +-------+---+---+---+
# |summary|  A|  B|  C|
# +-------+---+---+---+
# |  count|  5|  5|  5|
# |  count|  1|  1|  1|
# +-------+---+---+---+
```